# PySpark - new column partial regex matching from dictionary

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, mapping

I have a PySpark dataframe like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc_value |
| 2 | abc_value |
| 3 | some_other_value |
| 4 | anything_else |

I have a mapping dictionary:

```
d = {
"abc":"X",
"some_other":Y,
"anything":Z
}
```

I need to create new column in my original Dataframe which should be like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc_value | X |
| 2 | abc_value | X |
| 3 | some_other_value | Y |
| 4 | anything_else | Z |

I tried mapping like this:

`mapping_expr = f.create_map([f.lit(x) for x in chain(*d.items())])` and then applying it with `withColumn` however it is exact matching, however I need **partial** (regex) matching as you can see.

How to accomplish this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid in PySpark there's no implemented function that extracts substrings according to a defined dictionary; you probably need to resort to tricks.

In this case, you can first create a search string which includes all your dictionary keys to be searched:

```
keys = list(d.keys())
keys_expr = '|'.join(keys)

keys_expr
# 'abc|some_other|anything'
```

Then you can use [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) to extract **the first** key from `keys_expr` that we encounter in column `B`, if present (that's the reason for the `|` operator).
Finally, you can use dictionary `d` to replace the values in the new column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df\
  .withColumn('C', F.regexp_extract('B', keys_expr, 0))\
  .replace(d, subset=['C'])

df.show()

+---+----------------+---+
|  A|               B|  C|
+---+----------------+---+
|  1|       abc_value|  X|
|  2|       abc_value|  X|
|  3|some_other_value|  Y|
|  4|   anything_else|  Z|
+---+----------------+---+
```